# The combination of AI and Time Series Database

Tags: sql, time-series, artificial-intelligence, influxdb, cnosdb

is the combination of AI and Time Series databases necessary? What are the actual use cases that require AI and Time Series database combination？Big model training is so hot... If you have any ideas, please tell me, I really want have a talk with you. Thanks for your attention.